# How do I prevent my laptop screen from dimming when charger is connected and disconnected? (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS)

Tags: 20.04, power-management, brightness

When I plug in or disconnect my charger from my laptop (Acer Inspire 7 N19C5), running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, the brightness changes. I would like the brightness to stay the same when the power is connected or disconnected.

I read that changing this to false: `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim` to `false`  might help, but it's already set to false as I get this:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim
false
```

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. I tagged it 20.04. When I search the page, the only 12 I find is in your comment. I think you're wrong. @guiverc

Comment: There is a chance this is hardware related and not OS related. Could you stop the boot at the grub prompt and see if it dims there too? If so check bios for an option for this.

Comment: A *live* system could also be used to test your hardware (ie. @Rinzwind's suggestion).  If it was me, I'd test using a different OS to the Ubuntu 20.04 you're using (ie. a Debian system for example) using the equivalent of the "Try Ubuntu" option available on *live* media.  The reason for a different system is to try and use different software so the hardware is the major common factor (Debian is used as example; you could use Fedora or something else too)